# number of ways of distribution

Tags: algorithm, math

if we have n different things and we need to distribute them among m different people then how many ways can we do it such that for each of the m persons there is conditions that:
person 1 can have at least a things and at most b things
person 2 can have at least c things and at most d things 
.. and so on ?

```
e.g if n = 5 and m =3 and the conditions are:
person 1 can receive at least 0 and at most 1 gift
person 2 can receive at least 1 and at most 3 gift
person 3 can receive at least 1 and at most 4 gift
then the number of ways of distributing  these 5 gifts is 6((0 1 4), (0 2 3), (0 3 2), (1 1 3), (1 2 2), (1 3 1)).
```

One way i believe is to iterate through all possible combinations for each range and see which ones sum upto n , but can't think of an efficient algorithm.
Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. Specifically the *at most* part (without that, it's trivial). But I think you would have better luck on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your example seems to imply that the gifts are undistinguishable (all that matters is how many gifts each person receives, not which gifts), but your problem statement says "different things"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a generating function approach. Represent the number of objects that person `i` gets by the exponents of `x`. This means that if person `i` can have at least `3` and at most `7` things, this corresponds to the term

```
x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7
```

Remember to think of `+` as `OR` and `*` as `AND`. If we want to impose conditions and person `1` and person `2`, then multiply their functions together. For example, with person `1` having between `3` and `7` things, and say person `2` has at least `5` things, and add a third person with at most `10` things. Then we get:

```
(x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7) * (x^5 + x^6 + ... ) * (1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^10)
```

which can also be written as

```
(x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7) * ( x^5/(1+x) ) * (1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^10)
```

The way to get information back from this is the following. The coefficient of `x^M` in the expansion of these terms gives the number of ways to distribute a total of `M` things among all the people subject to the given constraints.

You can work this out from the formulas, or write a program to extract the coefficient, but the idea is to use generating functions as a convenient and efficient way to encode the constraints along with the answer.